# Django/bootstrap form : how to set and get btn-group value

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm beginner and use Python/Django/bootstrap. I googled and didn't find really the full answer to my question (code example).

On a form, I would like to use 3 buttons grouped to display and select the status of an alarm system which can be : Armed/Home/unarmed
I use the below HTML code:

```html
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
  <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></em> Armed
  </button> 
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
  <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-lamp"></em> Home
  </button> 
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
  <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></em> Unarm
  </button> 
</div>
```

The question is how to:

1. Highlight on of the 3 button to show the alarm status when
   entering the form
2. Get the button status (armed/home/unarmed) modofied by the user
   when leaving the form

Would it be possible you provide me the HTML code updated and the code of the urls.py and views.py to be added.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#active-state) you can do:

- ***set active button***: select the button of you interest and add the class active
- **preserve the class active**: on click you can preserve the active status only for the clicked button (remove this class from all the others)
- **get active button**: select the button with the active class

The demo:

```js
//
// set the second button active on DomReady
//
$('.btn-group-lg button').eq(1).addClass("active");


//
// Preserve the active status only for the clicked button
//
$('.btn-group-lg button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.btn-group-lg button').not(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});


//
// get the active button
//
$('#btnGetActive').on('click', function(e) {
  var btnActive = $('.btn-group-lg button.active');
  console.log(btnActive.text().trim() + ' is the ' + btnActive.index() + ' active');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="btnGetActive" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Get Active button</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></em> Armed
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-lamp"></em> Home
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></em> Unarm
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I modified the $('.btn-group-lg button').eq(0)..... with:
 $('.btn-group-lg button').eq( {{status}}) ... to pass the "status" parameter from my Pyhton code.
I had to put your code (scripts) in my base.html template to get them working.
I find that a bit dirty and would like to add them in the template where the buttons are (main.html).
How to use these scripts in the template where the buttons are instead of the base.html template?

Comment: @MMGG the js you intend to use in a page must be included there. I don't use Python but if you want to use templates remember to include the js code wherever you need. I hope this will help you.